# Display direct children of the current custom taxonomy in taxonomy.php template

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives

Let’s  say i have custom taxonomy named “Location” with hierarchial structure like the following :

> - ASIA
>
>   - CHINA
>   - INDIA
>   - JAPAN
>
>     - Fukuoka
>     - Hokkaido
>     - Okinawa
>     - Tokyo
>
>       - Akishima
>       - Machida
>       - Tachikawa
>       - ...
> - AFRICA
> - AMERICA
> - EUROPE
> - ...

On the taxonomy archive template (taxonomy.php) ,  i  want to display links to all DIRECT CHILD of the current taxonomy being viewed.

So for example,  if someone view the “ASIA” archive page they will see link to CHINA, INDIA, and JAPAN archive page only and exclude the “grandchildren” taxonomy.

Then if someone view  the JAPAN archive page they will see a link to FUKUOKA, HOKKAIDO, OKINAWA, and TOKYO only .  Same behavior until it reach the taxonomy with no children  and obviously nothing will be displayed

Please  help me what to do, i’ve tried several method but none of them work.

Most of the solution i found only manage to display ALL the children taxonomy including the grandchildren.

So instead work  like i explained above, the “ASIA” archive page will display  all link to  CHINA, INDIA, JAPAN, Fukooka, Hokkaido, Tokyo, Akishima, .....

I want to display ONLY the direct children of the current taxonomy and exclude the grandchildren.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories). The `wp_list_categories` allows you to set a `child_of` and a `depth` (in this case 1, we only want to go one level down).

See the link to the Codex about styling it; there's a whole host of options.

```
<?php $term = get_queried_object();
     wp_list_categories(array(
       'taxonomy'=>$term->taxonomy,
       'child_of'=>(int) $term->term_id,
       'hide_empty'=>0,
       'depth'=>1,
  )); ?>
```

I've only tested this on built-in categories, but this should work for custom taxonomies too.

Comment: Awesome!, this work flawlessly. thank you very much..